# Why is openjdk-17 in openjdk-17-jdk package empty?

Tags: package-management, java, 22.04, openjdk

I just installed `openjdk-17-jdk` package on fresh Ubuntu 22.04. It created two directories in `/usr/lib/jvm`:

- `java-17-openjdk-amd64` (which contains JDK)
- `openjdk-17` (which is empty)

At least that's what I think happened, judging by modification date - there is also a `java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64`, which points to `java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64` which is weird since it seems it was modified before the system was installed.

Looking for my JDK, I first went to `openjdk-17`, but then I noticed this one doesn't contain any elements. Why is that? Is this directory needed?

Comment: Try asking dpkg what should have been installed and where: `dpkg -L <package_name>`

Comment: @user535733 `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17` and `/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64` are listed under `openjdk-17-jdk`. `java-1.17.0-openjdk-amd64` is not.